# Uploading file from Blazor WebAssembly App directly to Blob storage

Tags: file-upload, azure-blob-storage, blazor, shared-access-signatures

I've been trying to develop a Blazor WebAssembly app (I'm trying with both .NET Standard 2.1 and .NET 5.0) and my goal is to allow the user to select a file using `InputFile`and for that file to be uploaded to an Azure Blob Storage Container. I've been looking around a lot and following different guides here and there but with no success. The issues I was obtaining were usually related to security for example CORS (Although it had been fully set up), Authorization fails and System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms is not supported on this platform.

Regardless of whether it is good practice or not; is it possible to directly upload to a blob storage from a blazor app? One method i tried was via a **SAS** token. It works via a CONSOLE APP but not a BLAZOR APP.

```
<label for="browseData"><b>Browse File</b></label>
<p><InputFile id="browseData" OnChange="@OnInputFileChange" /></p>

private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var maxAllowedFiles = 1;

    var inputFile = e.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles).First();

    var stream = inputFile.OpenReadStream();

    await StorageService.UploadFileToStorage(stream, "sftp-server", inputFile.Name);
}
```

**Storage Service**

```
public class AzureStorageService

{
    private readonly IAzureStorageKeyService _azureStorageKeyService;

    public AzureStorageService(IAzureStorageKeyService azureStorageKeyService)
    {
        _azureStorageKeyService = azureStorageKeyService;
    }

    public async Task<Uri> UploadFileToStorage(Stream stream, string container, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            const string REPLACE_THIS_ACCOUNT = "test";

            var blobUri = new Uri("https://"
                                  + REPLACE_THIS_ACCOUNT +
                                  ".blob.core.windows.net/" +
                                  container + "/" + fileName);
            // Create the blob client.

            AzureSasCredential azureSasCredential = new AzureSasCredential(
                "?sv=2019-12-12&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2021-01-20T04:21:45Z&st=2021-01-19T20:21:45Z&spr=https&sig=OIkLePYDcF2AChtYUKs0VxUajs4KmwSyOXpQkFLvN2M%3D");

            var blobClient = new BlobClient(blobUri, azureSasCredential);

            // Upload the file
            var response = await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true);

            return blobUri;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Like I was mentioning this will work via a console app but not a blazor app due to CORS..is this a security feature that just cannot be bypassed and just has to be done via the server side through a function -> blob?

Comment: Hi @godlypython. Have any of the answers solved your question/issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to upload a file with your code. It was working like a charm. So, there is no error in your source code. I used the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly` SDK with `net5.0` as the target framework. Probably, it's a configuration issue with the storage account.

[image: CORS policies]

The CORS policy allows the host of the application (https://localhost:5001) to accesses the resources with any verb and any header (*) values. The response can include the `content-length` header. Is your WASM self hosted or hosted within an ASP core application? You can easily spot what origin is sent to azure by inspected the request.

[image: what origin is used to send a request]

Based on your context, only a few verbs like **PUT** might be enough.

The configuration of the SAS key can also be more specific.

[image: Configuration for SAS]

**Using SAS from Blazor WASM**

Even not entirely part of your questions, but worth mentioning. If you want to allow a direct upload into your blob storage - and there are good reasons for it - before uploading a file, your WASM app should send a request to your API, the response contains the SAS key that can only be used for this one operation. The SAS key itself should be a [user delegation SAS key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#user-delegation-sas)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to directly upload file to Azure blob in Blazor WebAssembly application, we need to configure CORS fro Azure storage account. Regarding how to configure it, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services).

For example

Configure CORS

```
Allowed origins: *
Allowed verbs: DELETE,GET,HEAD,MERGE,POST,OPTIONS,PUT
Allowed headers: *
Exposed headers: *
Maximum age (seconds): 3600
```

[image]

[Create Account SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas).
[image]

My upload file compoment

```
@page "/fileupload"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using System.IO
@using System.Linq
@using System.Threading
@using Azure.Storage.Blobs
@using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models
@using Azure.Storage
@using Azure


<h3>File Upload Component</h3>
<label for="browseData"><b>Browse File</b></label>
<p><InputFile id="browseData" OnChange="@OnInputFileChange" /></p>
@{
    var progressCss = "progress " + (displayProgress ? "" : "d-none");
}

<div class="@progressCss">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="@($"width: { progressBar }%")" aria-valuenow="@progressBar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>

@code {
    private bool displayProgress = false;
    private string result = string.Empty;
    private string progressBar;
    private int maxAllowedSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var maxAllowedFiles = 1;

        var inputFile = e.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles).First();

        var blobUri = new Uri("https://"
                                  + "23storage23" +
                                  ".blob.core.windows.net/" +
                                  "upload" + "/" + inputFile.Name);


        AzureSasCredential credential = new AzureSasCredential("");
        BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(blobUri, credential, new BlobClientOptions());
        displayProgress = true;

        var res = await blobClient.UploadAsync(inputFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize), new BlobUploadOptions
        {
            HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = inputFile.ContentType },
            TransferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions
            {
                InitialTransferSize = 1024 * 1024,
                MaximumConcurrency = 10
            },
            ProgressHandler = new Progress<long>((progress) =>
            {
                progressBar = (100.0 * progress / inputFile.Size).ToString("0");

            })

        });





    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Besides, you also can download my [sample](https://github.com/JimXu199545/FileUpload) to do a test.